# Divergence free property preserved under weak convergence in $L^2$

Tags: sobolev-spaces, weak-convergence, strong-convergence

Given $\Psi =\{ u \in H^1_0(\Omega) : \mathrm{div}(u)=0  \in \Omega\}$ equipped with $ H^1(\Omega)$ norm  , and $\Phi$ is the closure of $\Psi$ for the $L^2(\Omega)$ norm ,it is equipped with $L^2(\Omega)$ norm.

We have $\xi_m  \in \Psi $ for all $m$. Such that it is weakly convergent to $\xi$ in $L^2(\Omega)$

How can I prove that $\mathrm{div}(\xi) =0 $ in $\Omega$

I have proceed as follows:
From the density of $\Psi$ in $\Phi$ , I can take a subsequence $\xi_{m,k}$ that converges to $\xi_m$ strongly in $L^2(\Omega)$ but we also can say that $\xi_{m,k}$ is weakly convergent to $\xi $ in $L^2(\Omega)$

So we get $\xi_{m,k}$ is strongly convergent to $\xi$ in $L^2(\Omega)$  this strong convergence leads to convergence in the sense of distributions, and since divergence operator is continuous in distribution sense then we deduce that the $\mathrm{div
}(\xi)$ is zero.

Is this correct? Any help please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step is to state the goal precisely. The identity $\operatorname{div}\xi=0$ can only be expected to hold in the weak sense, as
$$
\int_\Omega \xi\cdot \nabla \phi = 0 \quad \forall \phi\in H^1_0(\Omega)
\tag1 $$
Weak convergence $\xi_m\to \xi$ in $L^2(\Omega)$ preserves (1) since $\nabla \phi\in L^2(\Omega)$; this is essentially the definition of weak convergence.

One cannot expect  $\operatorname{div}\xi=0$ to hodl in the classical sense; $\xi$ need not be differentiable.

Comment: Thank you, Now,if in addition I have the $\xi \in H^1(\Omega)$, will the result hold in the classical sense?